# How to execute php file in Drupal 6 by Cron

Tags: drupal, cron

What I need is execute one php file every hour. I found a lot of weird and not-understandable things about creating a module for Drupal (I don't need a whole module, I need to execute just ONE file).

Because my brain can't handle this dull realisation of Drupal or Cron.

Comment: what is the file name . Pls give the entire path and if possible function name in the file u want to run

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with running this script? It may be more useful to use one of Drupal's hooks. (Side note: why are you using Drupal 6?)

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use system `crontab` because it reduces load to php and your site will run faster.
Read more:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
- http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm.

If you can't use system cron try to configure Drupal's cron: https://www.drupal.org/cron.

In worse case you can try https://www.drupal.org/project/poormanscron module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the Drupal-y way, instead of a more hacky way outside of what Drupal is meant to do, use `hook_cron()`.

To do this, you will need to create a new module with that function inside of `module_name.module`. You can view the documentation on creating a new module in Drupal six [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/206753). You should only need the "Getting Started" and "Tell Drupal about your module" sections.

In your `module_name.module` file, write a `hook_cron()` function. The `hook` will be replaced by the machine-name of your module.

The description of `hook_cron()` on Drupal.org is as follows:

> Modules that require to schedule some commands to be executed at regular intervals can implement hook_cron(). The engine will then call the hook at the appropriate intervals defined by the administrator. This interface is particularly handy to implement timers or to automate certain tasks. Database maintenance, recalculation of settings or parameters, and automatic mailings are good candidates for cron tasks.

Without more details of what you are trying to accomplish or more details about your script, this is all I can provide.